# Hyperplane dividing corners of a hypercube into 2 sets

Tags: linear-algebra, polytopes

Consider the corners of a hypercube in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where each corner of the hypercube is a point of the form $(\pm1, \dotsc, \pm1) \in \{\pm1\}^n$. Index the corners with the notation:

$$\mathbf{c}_i; i \in \{1, \dotsc, 2^n\}$$

Let $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^n, b \in \mathbb{R}$ be parameters of a hyperplane $\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{x} = b$. Define a split of the hypercube to be a collection of 2 sets:

$$\bigl\{ \{\mathbf{c_i} \mid \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{c}_i \geq b\}, \{\mathbf{c}_j \mid \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{c}_j < b\}\bigr\}$$

1. How many unique splits of the hypercube exist?
2. Given a hyperplane parameterized by specific $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^n, b \in \mathbb{R}$, it produces a split $S$. How many splits are there that are different from $S$ by only 1 corner? For each such split, what are the parameters for a corresponding hyperplane in terms of $\mathbf{a}, b, \mathbf{c}_i \in \{\pm1\}^n$?

If helpful, you may reindex the corners using some specific transformation. For example, you may reindex the corners by their distance from the hyperplane (i.e. $\frac{|\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{x} - b|}{\|\mathbf{a}\|}$) in ascending order.

This didn't jump out to me as any kind of unsolved problem, but an acceptable answer would be to show this reduces to some unsolved problem if that's the case.

Comment: Nice problem. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried thinking about being given a specific $\mathbf{a}$ and tuning around the $b$ term. As the hyperplane approaches the hypercube along the plane's axis, it'll move points from 1 side to the other. My friend and I came up with a sketch of proof   (similar to a diagonalization proof) to show that there's always some hyperplane that can separate the corners with a strict inequality wrt $b$ for a finite dimensional hypercube.

Comment: I also tried thinking about it combinatorically in terms of the different order of points moved to the other split in the above construction. I'm confused about how to not double count splits that move corners to the other side in different orders, but at some point along their respective paths create the same split.

Comment: To make the above construction more clear, I changed $b$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ and examined the order of corners getting moved to the other side. If 
2 corners are moved to the other side at the same time, then we can tweak the hyperplane a little bit so it still produces the same ordering on the corners, but is forced to also order the 2 corners that were previously moved at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first question is essentially known. Another way to phrase it is how many distinct functions are there of the form $f(\mathbf{x})=\text{sgn}(\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x}-b)$ restricted to the Boolean hypercube. It has been known that each such linear threshold function is uniquely determined by the $n+1$ *Chow parameters*, $\hat{f}(\emptyset), \hat{f}(\{1\}),\ldots,\hat{f}(\{n\})$, where $\hat{f}(S)$ for $S\subseteq [n]$ are the discrete Fourier coefficients of $f$. It is also well-known that each Fourier coefficient is an integer multiple of $1/2^n$ that lies in $[-1,1]$, and therefore, there are at most $2^{n+1}$ choices of value for each of these $n+1$ coefficients. These two facts immediately imply that there are at most $2^{(n+1)^2}$ such linear threshold functions.

The natural, and more involved, question is whether this asymptotic estimate is right. An easy construction of a family of $3^n$ such subsets comes from considering the faces of the Boolean hypercube. This lower bound is incredibly loose, however. It is actually known that there are at least $2^{n^2-O(n^2/\log n)}$ such functions, so this estimate is essentially tight.

For more information on the upper bound, check out Chapter 5 of O'Donnell's book on harmonic analysis of Boolean functions. The lower bounds are a bit harder to find...there's a reference [here](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=dm&paperid=786&option_lang=eng), but it seems to be in Russian...

Comment: What does the notation $[n]$ mean? I'm familiar with bracket notation when specifying a closed interval, but that doesn't make sense in context here.

Comment: Oh sorry, it just means $\{1,\ldots, n\}$.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm wondering if you can you the same reasoning to bound the number linear threshold functions on a strict subset of the Boolean hypercube?